# Tecla ENTER salvar tabela ao invés de espaçar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela que deixar editar diretamente no grid:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os códigos dela:

> Tabela MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `php_interview_questions` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `row_order` int(8) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `php_interview_questions` (`id`, `question`, `answer`, `row_order`) VALUES
(1, 'PHP array functions example', 'is_array(), in_array(), array_keys(),array_values()', 3),
(2, 'How to redirect using PHP', 'Using header() function', 4),
(3, 'Differentiate PHP size() and count():', 'Same. But count() is preferable.', 1),
(4, 'What is PHP?', 'A server side scripting language.', 0),
(5, 'What is php.ini?', 'PHP configuration file.', 2);
```

> DB Controller:

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "blog_examples";

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$sql = "SELECT * from php_interview_questions";
$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>PHP MySQL Inline Editing using jQuery Ajax</title>
        <style>
            body{width:610px;}
            .current-row{background-color:#B24926;color:#FFF;}
            .current-col{background-color:#1b1b1b;color:#FFF;}
            .tbl-qa{width: 100%;font-size:0.9em;background-color: #f5f5f5;}
            .tbl-qa th.table-header {padding: 5px;text-align: left;padding:10px;}
            .tbl-qa .table-row td {padding:10px;background-color: #FDFDFD;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }        
           });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
       <table class="tbl-qa">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-header" width="10%">Q.No.</th>
                <th class="table-header">Question</th>
                <th class="table-header">Answer</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>
              <tr class="table-row">
                <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'question','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["question"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["answer"]; ?></td>
              </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

> saveedit.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_interview_questions set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
?>
```

A tabela esta toda funcionando perfeitamente, a unica coisa que quero mudar é seguinte, quando edito um valor e dou `ENTER` a linha quebra pra baixo,se eu clicar na tela em algum lugar vago a mesma salva o que foi digitado,o que eu quero, quando eu pressionar a tecla `ENTER` acontecer da mesma forma que se eu clica-se na tela,salva-se minha informação.

Fonte da tabela: [PhpPot Home](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/) (Caso queiram ver,lá tem uma demo.)

@Diego Souza

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca no `TD` um `onkeydown` chamando os mesmos parâmetros do `onblur`.

```
onKeyDown="checkEnter(event, this,'question','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')"
```

Mas chamando a função abaixo:

```
function checkEnter(e, editableObj, column, id){
   if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
      saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id);
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: fiz as alterações mais continua espaçando para baixo

Comment: Esqueci de passar o evento.

Comment: Veja agora se dá certo.

Comment: Estranho, continua dando erro.

Comment: Veja se está entrando dentro do IF.

Comment: Veja o que o console do chrome esta me retornado,sabe o que é ? adicionei a pergunta,adicionei também as minhas linhas,talvez esteja fazendo errado.

Comment: Arrumei o código, dê uma olhada e testa.

Comment: Deu certo,não sei se é possível mais deixa eu implementar uma pergunta: quando faz o processo ele só atualiza aquele campo (como se fosse um re-flash nele), e possível eu fazer isso na linha toda? e também após fazer o processo o campo sair da edição ?

Comment: Sim. É possível. Mas acredito que isso caiba melhor numa outra pergunta.

Comment: se puder me ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178849/tabela-edit%C3%A1vel-dar-re-flash-nos-campos-fechando-o-campo-editavel