# Como implementar tabela editável, atualizando os campos no banco de dados automaticamente

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho a seguinte tabela que deixa editar diretamente nas células:

Os códigos estão em 4 partes:

> Tabela MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `php_interview_questions` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `row_order` int(8) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `php_interview_questions` (`id`, `question`, `answer`, `row_order`) VALUES
(1, 'PHP array functions example', 'is_array(), in_array(), array_keys(),array_values()', 3),
(2, 'How to redirect using PHP', 'Using header() function', 4),
(3, 'Differentiate PHP size() and count():', 'Same. But count() is preferable.', 1),
(4, 'What is PHP?', 'A server side scripting language.', 0),
(5, 'What is php.ini?', 'PHP configuration file.', 2);
```

> DB Controller:

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "blog_examples";

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$sql = "SELECT * from php_interview_questions";
$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>PHP MySQL Inline Editing using jQuery Ajax</title>
        <style>
            body{width:610px;}
            .current-row{background-color:#B24926;color:#FFF;}
            .current-col{background-color:#1b1b1b;color:#FFF;}
            .tbl-qa{width: 100%;font-size:0.9em;background-color: #f5f5f5;}
            .tbl-qa th.table-header {padding: 5px;text-align: left;padding:10px;}
            .tbl-qa .table-row td {padding:10px;background-color: #FDFDFD;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
    <script>
    function showEdit(editableObj) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#F0E68C");
    } 

    function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveedit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
    function checkEnter(e, editableObj, column, id){
       if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
          saveToDatabase(editableObj, column, id);
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>      
       <table class="tbl-qa">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-header" width="10%">Q.No.</th>
                <th class="table-header">Question</th>
                <th class="table-header">Answer</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>
              <tr class="table-row">
                <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" 
                onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer2','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')"
                onKeyDown="checkEnter(event, this,'answer2','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" 
                onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["question"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["answer"]; ?></td>
              </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

> saveedit.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_interview_questions set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
?>
```

A alteração que preciso deve, após a alteração do texto de um campo e um clique fora da tabela (perder o foco), atualizar os dados no banco.

Como poderia fazer isso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações nos seus arquivos, resumindo:

1. Não utilize **mysql_**, utilize **mysqli_**
2. Quando executa-se um comando UPDATE, o resultado esperado é TRUE e não "mysqli_result" para passar à função mysqli_fetch_assoc, então tem que alterar o método RunQuery
       $result = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);

   ```
   if (( $result !== false ) && ( $result !== true ) )
   {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
       {
           $resultset[] = $row;
       }                               
   }
   ```
3. Para verificar os parâmetros que o JQUERY envia durante o Ajax, construa um método BeforeSend.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: "saveedit.php",
       type: "POST",
       data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
       beforeSend: function(){ console.log('column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id); },
       success: function(data){
           $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
       }        
   });
   ```
4. Na construção da tabela, na primeira coluna, você escreveu errado os parâmetros: **answer2** ?

```
    onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'answer2','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>;')"
    onKeyDown="checkEnter(event, this,'answer2','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')"
    onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $faq[$k]["question"]; ?></td>
```

Pra ver o resultado baixe esse arquivo: http://angar27.com.br/zzz/otacio.zip